# Should a bridge device and network interface card share the same IP address?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, bridge

If I create a bridge device and then set it as the master of my NIC then it appears that both devices have the same IP and two mac addresses. Is this correct?

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.16/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 2592sec preferred_lft 2142sec

3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.16/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 3370sec preferred_lft 3370sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:feaf:a125/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: veth1@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns ns1
    inet 169.254.31.45/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute veth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Is it a layer-2 bridge? ([OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) Don't you need two interfaces to bridge? (eg eth0 eth1, the bridge being br0)

Comment: @e2-e4 Uh, I assume so? I wasn't aware there are such a thing as a layer 3 bridge. I updated the question. I left out the fact that there is also a veth interface. Also, br0 and eth0 by themselves makes two interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a correct configuration. Bridge ports (`eth0` and `veth1` in your case) shouldn't have any ip addresses.

Comment: That seems logical to me... so why do they have them? I tried flushing them and they immediately return.

Comment: Check your network configuration tool. What do you use? NetworkManager? Plan? Systemd-networkd?

Comment: @Chris_F I'm guessing they will be ignored, only the br0 one matters

Comment: @AntonDanilov I'm new to linux networking so I'm not even sure what the options are. I created the interfaces using the `ip` command.

Comment: @AntonDanilov This is Raspbian so I think that I may have tracked the issue down to it's use of dhcpcd, which I read tries to assign a dhcp ip address to every interface and defaults to 169.254.x.x when unavailable...

Comment: dhcp clients bypass most of the network stack by (the need of) using raw sockets (to handle source address 0.0.0.0). So it would be able to communicate with a dhcp server over the wrong interface and assign the address, without involving the bridge and routing paths (which would have prevented this to work: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-linux-bridge-isolation#bridge-processing )